# Passing an array of pointers by reference

Tags: c, windows, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, string-parsing

I'm trying to get commands from the keyboard in a similiar fashion as command line args `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`but in a separate function. When I parse and print them within the scope of the `getCmd()` function all looks and behaves as intended, but as soon as they return to the main function they become a bunch of garbage. My questions are below the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getCmd(char *cmd, char *args[])
{
    char input[81] = { 0 };
    char *next_token = NULL;
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(input, 81, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
    cmd = strtok_s(input, " ", &next_token);
    if (!strcmp(cmd, "mv"))
    {
        args[0] = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        args[1] = strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token);
        printf("\n\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", cmd, args[0], args[1]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *cmd = NULL, *args[5];

    cmd = (char *)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)5; i++)
    {
        args[i] = (char *)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    }
    getCmd(cmd, args);
    printf("\n\n%s \n%s\n%s", cmd, args[0], args[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think its relevant but I'm using VS 2015 Community with the Visual C++ compiler on a 64 bit processor, Windows 7 OS.

My questions:

> - How should I pass the cmd and args[] by reference?
> - Are there any widely accepted idioms that deal with this sort of situations?

I've looked trough a few of the similiar questions and couldn't find a solution that works in this context, if the question is a duplicate, tell me and I'll close it.Since I'm new to stackoverflow any question formatting tips would be greatly appreciated. Cheers! (:

Comment: Introduce another level of indirection.

Comment: Why would anyone pass a pointer by reference?

Comment: @farukdgn: To allocate memory down inside the function and access is  inside the caller.

Comment: @alk why don't you just send the pointer itself?

Comment: @farukdgn: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: C does not support pass by reference. It is strictly pass by value. So no, you can't. And don't cast the result of `calloc` & friends in C. Or use unnecessary casts in general like `(size_t)5`. Or _magic numbers_. Or ...

Comment: @Olaf I agree, the code is far from finished. I wasn't aware that C doesn't support directly pass by reference, because this is my first language, will have to do more reading, anyway thanks for the suggestions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok_s()` return pointer into the buffer it's parsing (`input` here).

`input` lives on `getCmd()` stack. It dies the moment `getCmd()` returns. From then on the addresses pointing into `input` and that had been stored in `args`'s elements does not point to valid memory any more.

The code needs allocate fresh memory and copy what `strtok_s()` returned a pointer to.

Have a look on ow this can be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getCmd(char **pcmd, char *args[], size_t s)
{
    char input[81] = { 0 };
    char *next_token = NULL;
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(input, 81, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
    (*pcmd) = _strdup(strtok_s(input, " ", &next_token));
    if (!strcmp(*pcmd, "mv"))
    {
        args[0] = _strdup(strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token));
        args[1] = _strdup(strtok_s(NULL, " ", &next_token));
        printf("\n\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n", *pcmd, args[0], args[1]);
    }
}


#define ARGS_MAX (5)

int main(void)
{
    char *cmd, *args[ARGS_MAX] = {0};

    getCmd(&cmd, args, ARGS_MAX);
    printf("\n\n%s \n%s\n%s", cmd, args[0], args[1]);

    /* Clean up. */
    free(cmd);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARGS_MAX; ++i)
    {
      free(args[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this `strtok_s`?  ;-)

Comment: I silently assumed it would be `strtok_r()` renamed by some company in Redmond.... :} @AndrewHenle

Comment: @alk. AndrewHenle: Not this time. It is part of the optional "bound-checking interfaces": http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.3.1

Comment: @alk Thanks, it works like a charm. Is there any reason using strtok_r instead of _s, I couldn't find any documentation on MSDN about _r.

Comment: @Olaf: Unfortunately you seem to be wrong: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx

Comment: I give up here ... name clashs are fatal :-(

Comment: @alk - reloaded, comment deleted `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to approach the problem. While you are free to dynamically allocate memory for `cmd` and your `args` array, there is really no need, for this limited amount of memory you can use a static declaration for all. There is no need for a separate `input` array, you cause use `cmd` for that purpose and then tokenize `cmd`. This provides the benefit of leaving the first token *nul-terminated* in `cmd` after `strtok` is called.

**note:** in the example below, `strtok` is used, `strtok_s` was an optional compiler addition in C11, and unfortunately, I don't have a compiler that implements that option, so I test with `strtok`. You can easily make the change for VS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { NARGS = 5, MAXC = 128 };

size_t getcmd (char *cmd, char (*args)[MAXC]);

int main (void) {

    char cmd[MAXC] = "", args[NARGS][MAXC] = { "" };
    size_t i, n;

    if (!(n = getcmd (cmd, args))) return 1;

    printf ("  %s", cmd);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(" %s", args[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

size_t getcmd (char *cmd, char (*args)[MAXC])
{
    char *delim = " ,.\t\n";
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;

    printf ("$ ");
    if (!fgets (cmd, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    strtok (cmd, delim);            /* terminate after 1st token */

    for (p = strtok (NULL, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim)) {
        strncpy (args[idx++], p, MAXC);  /* limit to avail chars */
        if (idx == NARGS) break;    /* limit to available bounds */
    }

    return idx;
}
```

Note above, the return type of `getcmd` is `size_t`. Always choose a meaningful type to return an indication of success/failure as well as returning some needed information (the number of arguments here). Also note the C-Style Guide disfavors *camelCase* variable/function names preferring all lower-case instead. Leave *camelCase* names for C++. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getcmd
$ mv /this/here/file /that/there/file
  mv /this/here/file /that/there/file

$ ./bin/getcmd
$ mv -i --strip-trailing-slashes /this/here/file /that/there/file
  mv -i --strip-trailing-slashes /this/here/file /that/there/file
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any additional questions.